# Download Django 1.3 Official Release Fail

Tags: django

When I try to download the 1.3 version of Django in Ubuntu 10.4, it saves it as index.html.

```
wget http://www.djangoproject.com/download/1.3/tarball/
```

I've done this successfully in the past.  Python2.6 is installed. No previous versions of django are installed.

What gives?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
wget --trust-server-name http://www.djangoproject.com/download/1.3/tarball/
```

Or you can manually force the name using:

```
wget -O Django-1.3.tar.gz http://www.djangoproject.com/download/1.3/tarball/
```

Comment: Thanks Chris, that absolutely worked. Why was my original link an issue this time?  Normally, it works

Comment: That link redirects to an index.html page that serves up the tarball. The wget documentation is quite lacking on --trust-server-name and why it's required in scenarios like these. (curl does this automatically). I believe it has some security implication, but not sure exactly why.

Comment: @ChrisPratt how to download with **curl**

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it redirects to http://media.djangoproject.com/releases/1.3/Django-1.3.tar.gz